# Can I rename the step_definitions folder for Cucumber?

Tags: cucumber

Cucumber works great for Behavior Driven Development, but I'd like to use shorter directory names. features/step_definitions? Why not features/steps? I suppose there is some way to change this in the cucumber.yml file, but I haven't had any luck finding a .yml file that does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to do anything. Cucumber searches for step definitions in subdirectories of 'features', so features/steps works the same as features/step_definitions.